# Previous employment data in DS-160: listing a defunct company

Tags: visas, usa, applications

I've been filling my DS-160 application for a B2 visa, and I notice they ask for information of your previous employers. The problem is, the company I used to work last year is now defunct. I have contact information of the company, even their phone number at the time, but I fear they won't answer anymore. (And phone number is not optional).

Should I write all the phone number anyways? Should I specify something?

Comment: You should provide the information you had i.e. the latest phone numbers and emails. If there's space to explain, do so. If the US Consulates chooses to research it, they will be able to confirm such a company existed and is now defunct.

Comment: @Phantom please post your answer as an answer instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the DS-160 form asks applicants to provide employment history for the previous five years, it would be an oversight to omit it. Although the company no longer operates, provide the last known address and phone number. In the section where you're asked to briefly desribe your duties there, at the end of that statement you might simply add that the company ceased operations in month/year. Consular officials understand that companies fold and would be able to verify that, should it be necessary. Not including the company leaves an untidy gap in your employment history and the application.

Comment: To add, the new supplementary form, DS-5535, wants employment history for fifteen years, no one can realistically expect that all companies stay an operating concern that long.

Comment: @chx +1 great point; ty

Comment: or indeed that you'd even remember the names and contact information of your managers at all those companies (especially given that employment is ever more short term only, even a 2 year contract becoming a rarity in many sectors).